# SQL Database Mail sudden failure with Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

Trying to send email from database server to internal company mail, used to work properly until recently

Failed with the following error message:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 . Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).  )

Tried
restarted the database mail service, still failed

`exec msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_status_sp`

shows STARTED status

```
sp_CONFIGURE 'show advanced', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_CONFIGURE 'Database Mail XPs', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO 
sp_CONFIGURE 'show advanced', 0
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

config updated but still failed to send out mail

Anything else I can check?

Answer (score 0):

Update on issue:

Found that the server the mail profile has been configured to has been decommissioned. Changing that to the new server fixed the issue